# How is this iOS UI element called?

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit

My question is how this UI element is called. A link with a tutorial would be great :)

[image]

Comment: It's just a view controller presented as popup

Comment: Thank you for your fast response can you answer the question so i can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a view controller presented as pop up over the previous view controller.

Note that presentation style is just available on iPad.